# Variable wont echo

Tags: php, variables

I have the following code, where the var $username doesn't echo, when you type in a value.

```
//TODO: SET AUTH TOKEN as random hash, save in session
$auth_token =  rand();   

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Login')
{

    $errors = array(); //USED TO BUILD UP ARRAY OF ERRORS WHICH ARE THEN ECHOED
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if ($username = '')
    {
        $errors['username'] = 'Username is required';
    }

    echo $username; // var_dump($username) returns string 0
}


require_once 'login_form.html.php';

 ?>
```

login_form is this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="<?php echo $auth_token ?>">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password1">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Login">
</form>
```

The auth token part isn't important, it just when I type in a value in username textbox and press the login button, the username wont echo, var_dump returns string (0) and print_r is just blank.

Answer (score 3):

silly mistake

```
if ($username = '')   <-- this is an assignment
```

Should be this

```
if ($username == '')  <-- this is comparison
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($username = '')
```

You're missing a `=`, so you're assigning an empty string to `$username`. Change it to

```
if ($username == '')
               ^-- note the 2 equal signs.
```

Comment: Some people say that writing your comparisons with the constant  on the left side is safer, e.g. `if ('' == $username)`, as you'd get an `unexpected =` error if you put in only a single `=`.

Comment: that makes sense...also not being awake at 4:43am should also help, also can I ask: who do you tick if all the answers are correct? The first right answer?

Answer (score 2):

This line is an assignment, not a comparison:

```
if ($username = '')
```

You want:

```
if ($username == '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//TODO: SET AUTH TOKEN as random hash
$auth_token =  rand();   

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Login')
{

    $errors = array(); //USED TO BUILD UP ARRAY OF ERRORS WHICH ARE THEN ECHOED
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if ($username == '') // **You are assiging not comparing** 
    {
        $errors['username'] = 'Username is required';
    }

    echo $username; // var_dump($username) returns string 0
}


require_once 'login_form.html.php';

 ?>
```

In your login form: (the action attribute..)

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="<?php echo $auth_token ?>">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username">
 Password: <input type="password" name="password1">
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Login">
 </form>
```

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` this is unnecessary...

Comment: Yes, that is for sure unnecessary, but what's the harm at remaining on safer side? Read this small article: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-empty-form-action-submit-to-current
Do read the commments too. :-)